# ¿Por qué setOnItemClickListener en listView no funciona?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Tengo un `listview` funcionando con `sqlite` dentro de un `fragment` pero al querer obtener el `id` de la lista con `setOnItemClickListener`, no funciona.

Asi lo hago:

```
 mClientesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            showSuccessMessage("El id es ");
            try{
                Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) mClienteAdapter.getItem(i);
                String currentClienteId = currentItem.getString(
                        currentItem.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
                showSuccessMessage("El id es "+ currentClienteId);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ClickCliente", "onItemClick: ",e );
            }

        }
    });
```

Pero no hace nada.

ACTUALIZACIÓN.
Al hacer un debug en la app, me muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego el código de la clase completo

```
public class f_clientes extends Fragment {
public static final int REQUEST_UPDATE_CLIENTE = 2;
private dbdata mDbCliente;
private ListView mClientesList;
private ClientesCursorAdapter mClienteAdapter;
private FloatingActionButton mAddCliente;
public f_clientes() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static f_clientes newInstance() {
   return new f_clientes();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_clientes, container, false);

    mClientesList=(ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.cliente_list);
    mClienteAdapter=new ClientesCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);

    mClientesList.setAdapter(mClienteAdapter);
    mDbCliente=new dbdata(getActivity());
    loadClientes();

    Log.i("MClientes", "Prueba toas");

    mClientesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            showSuccessMessage("El id es ");
            try{
                Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) mClienteAdapter.getItem(i);
                String currentClienteId = currentItem.getString(currentItem.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
                showSuccessMessage("El id es "+ currentClienteId);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ClickCliente", "onItemClick: ",e );
            }

        }
    });
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fab_btn_add_Cliente);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clienteid", "1");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return root;
}

private void loadClientes()
{
    Log.i("MClientes", "cargando clientes...");
   new ClientesLoadTask().execute();
}
private void showDetailScreen(String lawyerId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ClIENTE_ID, lawyerId);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_UPDATE_CLIENTE);
}
private void showSuccessMessage(String mensaje) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private class ClientesLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        return mDbCliente.getAllClientes();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mClienteAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        } else {
            // Mostrar empty state
        }
    }

}}
```

y este el layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.cspm.ventas6.cspm.v_fragments.f_clientes"
android:focusable="false">


<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clientes"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cliente_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_btn_add_Cliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

EL listview es llenado desde una tabla de un sqlite

Comment: Prueba con: `Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);`. Una pregunta, para entender más tu problema. ¿Depuraste el código para ver que pasaba?, ¿Te está lanzando la excepcion del catch?. En caso de que hayas pasado el cursor como parámetro a tu adapter intenta castearlo a tu clase del adaptador.

Comment: El catch no muestra nada, mClienteAdapter, es el que llena el listview

Comment: Ejecuta la app en modo debug y coloca un punto de depuración al comienzo osea en showSuccessMessage y corre la app paso por paso para saber que te devuelve cada objeto y cuéntame.

Comment: Me sale así haciendo debug, No such instance field: 'mClientesList', le subo una foto, actualizando la pregunta.

Comment: Agrega más código. Este error suele suceder por muchas razones. 1. Copiaste el código de algún sitio, lo compilaste y mientras estabas corriendo la App le cambiaste el nombre a la variable. 2. Lo estas inicializando mal el objeto. Te recomiendo que hagas clean & rebuild a tu solución. Si no, sería un problema relacionado a Pro guard en Android Studio. Edita la respuesta y agrega más código para ver si solucionamos esto.

Comment: Todo parece normal, intentaste hacer clean & rebuild de tu solución?

Comment: Me sale este mensaje en el logcat, no me había fijado.  W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

Comment: Eliminado el cardview del layout item que infla el listview y el setOnItemClickListener funciona, alguna propuedad con el cardview es el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado el problema, resulta que mi `layout` `item_producto`, tenia como padre un `cardview` y dentro de eso todo los `textviews`, solamente agregue estas propiedades

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Con eso se solucionó.

Answer (score 0):

He realizado pruebas y tengo un posible solucion, logro ya enviar un evento click desde un imagenview dentro de cada item que llena el curso, pero ahora no logro captar la posicion exacta del id,  asi tengo la funcion

```
 public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nombrecliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_cliente_nombre);
    TextView nombrelocal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre_negocio);
    ImageView btn_next= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_next_cliente);
    View mView =(View) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator_status);
    String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre));
    String negocio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo));
    idC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
    long idlng=cursor.getLong(0);
    int_id=Integer.parseInt(idC);
    int_id=int_id-6;
    idC=""+idlng;
    nombrecliente.setText(nombre + "id:  "+idC);
    nombrelocal.setText(negocio);
    mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("in view", "onClick id :"+idC);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clienteid", idC);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```